# freeing a void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

How to free a void pointer.

```
struct vStruct {
    void *vPtr;
    struct vStruct *next;
};

struct vStruct sObj;
struct vStruct *sObjNew = sObj;

delete sObjNew->vPtr; -----------> Is this correct way to delete void pointer
delete sObjNew;
```

Showing error Operator 'delete', applied to void* argument having has undefined behavior, and most likely does not invoke the object's destructor.

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, please don't forget to mark it as accepted, such that it will help further visitors to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not delete a `void` pointer. `delete` works for specific types (such that compiler knows, which destructor should be called - as stated in error message).

If you want to hold unspecified type in your structure, you have to wrap it somehow.

```
class DataWrapper
{
public:
    virtual void * GetData() = 0;            
    virtual ~DataWrapper()
    {
    }
};

class MyDataWrapper
{
protected:
    MyData * data;

public:
    MyDataWrapper(MyData * newData)
    {
        data = newData;
    }

    void * GetData()
    {
        return data;
    }

    ~MyDataWrapper()
    {
        delete data;
    }
};

struct vStruct
{
    MyDataWrapper * vPtr;
    struct vStruct *next;

    ~vStruct()
    {
        if (vPtr != null)
            delete vPtr;
    }
};

vStruct sObj;
sObj.vPtr = new MyDataWrapper(new MyData());

// When sObj gets deleted, MyDataWrapper is
// deleted too (thanks to the ~vStruct) and
// in effect, the allocated data is deleted too.
```

Note, that it's a simple example, it can be written more aesthetically.

Answer (score 9):

You do not `delete` a void pointer. Why? Because:

> 'delete', applied to `void*` argument has undefined behavior, and most likely does not invoke the object's destructor.

How would your compiler know which type the pointee object has? And therefore which destructor to call? (Though it can probably determine how much memory to free, depending on the allocation mechanism.)

Do not store a `void*` — use a "real" pointer type instead. If you need to "hide" the true type, consider employing *polymorphism* instead of antiquated C practices.

Answer (score 3):

How was `vPtr` initialised?

- If it points to data the struct doesn't own, you must not destroy it.
- If it points to data created using `malloc`, you should call `free`.
- If it points to data created using `new`, you'd need to cast it to the correct (or a compatible) type before calling `delete` to allow the correct destructor to be called.

Note that your example code won't compile but suggests `vPtr` is not being initialised at all. You must initialise `vPtr` in all `vStruct` instances you create.  Attempting to free an uninitialised `vPtr` would have undefined consequences but would likely crash.